# Does consumer and receiver use different protocol to connect to same exchange in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have small query related to exchange in rabbitMQ.

Is it possible for different clients to connect with a exchange in RabbitMQ with different protocols. will all the clients able to send or receive events from or to the exchange irrespective of the protocol clients have used to established a connection with exchange.

Please find below high level diagram just for understanding purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for different clients to connect with a exchange in RabbitMQ with different protocols

Yes, this is one of the best features of RabbitMQ. You just have to make sure the messages are routed to the correct queues.